# Data structure for querying a set of sets?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

Lets say I have a set of `n` elements, divided into a number of sets. Each element is in one set exactly.

I want to be able to do the following queries as quickly as possible:

1. What set `s` is element `e` in?
2. What elements `{e1,e2,...,ei}` are in set `s`?

What data structure should I use? The best I could think of is a map pointing to a bunch of sets but I was wondering if there's a better approach?

If it helps, you can assume my set is the integers `{0,1,...,n-1}`

Comment: Do you need to modify these sets?

Comment: After set up the main thing I need to be able to do is set unions

Comment: Have you considered http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure with some additional work to provide queries of 2nd kind?

Answer (score 0):

If your set is the integers {0,1,...,n-1} without gaps then it would be more efficient to use an array of sets; however if the integers are sparse then a map of sets would require less space.  Either way operation (1) would run in constant time (worst case for the array, average case for the hash map).